# Webpack not referencing woff2 files correctly

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm trying to create my first npm library that helps detect icons for filenames. It's based off of an [existing library](https://github.com/websemantics/file-icons-js), but I'm trying to make it webpack compatible so that I can use it in VueJS projects.

**Hierarchy**:

```
.
├── css
│   └── style.css
├── fonts
│   ├── devopicons.woff2
│   ├── file-icons.woff2
│   ├── fontawesome.woff2
│   ├── mfixx.woff2
│   └── octicons.woff2
├── index.js
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

The CSS file references external `woff2` files that are found in the package.

**style.css**:

```
...
@font-face {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    src: url("../fonts/fontawesome.woff2");
}
...
```

I import the above CSS file into my `index.js` to ensure that webpack picks it up as a dependency.

**index.js**:

```
import './css/styles.css'
...
class FileIcons {
  ...
}
export default new FileIcons()
```

**webpack.config.js**:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './index.js',
  mode: 'production',
  output: {
    library: 'FileIcons',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: path.join('css', 'bundle.js')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'css-loader' // translates CSS into CommonJS
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        // Match woff2 in addition to patterns like .woff?v=1.1.1.
        test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            // Limit at 20k. Above that it emits separate files
            limit: 20000,

            // url-loader sets mimetype if it's passed.
            // Without this it derives it from the file extension
            mimetype: 'application/font-woff',

            // Output below fonts directory
            name: 'fonts/[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  ...
  "main": "./dist/css/bundle.js",
  "files": [
    "dist/*",
    "css/*",
    "fonts/*",
    ".babelrc",
    ".eslintrc.js",
    "*.js",
    "LICENSE.md",
    "README.md",
    "*.json"
  ],
  ...
}
```

In my other project (Vue component), I'm importing this library as follows:

```
<template>
...
</template>
<script>
  import FileIcons from '@gurupras/file-icons-js'
  ...
</script>
```

Importing the file this way leads to `404` errors stating that `http://localhost:8080/fonts/octicons.<hash>.woff2` failed to be loaded.

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly set up webpack to treat this project as a library and reference the woff2 files correctly?

Comment: is this webpack 4 ? or earlier

Comment: This is webpack 4

Comment: I have added answer, is that generating any files in fonts folder?

Answer (score 0):

Try change in loader `name` `property` from `fonts/[name].[ext]` to `fonts/[name]_[hash].[ext]` like :

```
{
    // Match woff2 in addition to patterns like .woff?v=1.1.1.
    test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'url-loader',
      options: {
        // Limit at 20k. Above that it emits separate files
        limit: 20000,

        // url-loader sets mimetype if it's passed.
        // Without this it derives it from the file extension
        mimetype: 'application/font-woff',

        // Output below fonts directory
        name: 'fonts/[name]_[hash].[ext]'
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
I just notices you are using woff or woff2 for font awesome, Woff files are not supported by IE & EOT which is supported by IE is not supported by others. Same is for Safari, Android, iOS & legacy iOS supports truetype TTF not others So if want consistent font, try adding font-awesome package in npm or any package module you use, that will generate all required files in all format .

My application is in react with npm with SASS so I added font-awesome-sass package, you can add simple font-awesome package with all css files:

```
npm install --save font-awesome-sass
```

& imported in react like

```
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome-sass/assets/stylesheets/font-awesome";
```

any post compiling is done with same webpack that can add same hashes so I never referenced hash hard coded in code files, in fact in CI every build generates new hash.

Comment: Both, my code and this code generate files in the `dist/fonts` directory. The problem is that the requests are still being regarded as 404. Interestingly, I just noticed that although the files generated have a really long hash, the developer console is reporting `http://localhost:9080/fonts/octicons.de59a972.woff2`. (short hash). Could my vue component webpack config be messing things up? I'm using the default configuration. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: Actually fonts are supposed to be imported as whole so webpack assumes whole family of font, all files with same small hash is from same font family I think.

Comment: My point was that the filenames are all long-hash, but the HTTP requests are short-hash. Wouldn't this obviously lead to a 404? Unless webpack is somehow setting up routes to handle this internally..

Comment: I am updating answer, that need more space than comment

Comment: While informative, I don't think the updated answer applies to me. I've tried this on both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Try on IE or Safari on iPad or Air :) If users are more targeted towards chrome or firefox then it is redundant but I found many users are equally using Mac with safari & IE on windows too